# FindInBackground callback doesn't fire

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, cloud

I have a ListView with lazy loading , it works just fine but in random ,the `FindInBackground` which provide the ListView items doesn't return it's `FindCallBack()` method it goes forever and the application requests in other part of app is dead too and doesn't work either until i restart the app!(Network is not the problem).

i've defined my query like this :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.setSkip(10);
...
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
}
});
```